# What are the solutions to this equation (primes, modular arithmetic)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Given: $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $p$ is prime. Find the solutions to the following equation: 
$$m^2-3mn+(np)^2=12p$$

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x^2 + y^2$ is not divisible by $3$ unless the integers $x,y$ both are divisible by $3.$ That comes up as a question on this site fairly often.

If $p \neq 3,$ with the right hand side $12 p$ divisible by $3,$ we find that both $m $ and $np$ are divisible by $3,$ and $p \neq 3$ so $n$ is divisible by $3.$ That means the left hand side is divisible by $9,$ but the right hand side is not when $p \neq 3.$

When $p=3,$ we are trying to solve
$$ m^2 - 3mn + 9 n^2 = 36.  $$ I find the integer solutions
$$ (6,2); (6,0); (0,2); (0,-2)$$
with $m \geq 0$ so  your only answer is
$$ p = 3, \; \;  m = 6, \; \; n = 2. $$

P. S. The problem $m^2-3mn+(np)^2=p$ is more interesting. It is possible for $p=2$ with $m=n=1.$ It is not possible for $p=3.$ It is also not possible for $p \geq 5,$ because the prime $p$ is integrally represented by $p x^2 + 3xy + p y^2,$ which is Gauss reduced, does not represent $1,$ therefore is not the same class as the principal form. The theorem involved is that a prime is represented by at most one class of a discriminant, along with its opposite class. Of course,  $p x^2 + 3xy + p y^2$ is self-opposite or "ambiguous."